# Cannot get css hover to action

Tags: css, hover

I've been struggling to hover to work. All this should do is have a red container div and when you hover it, a black inner div drops down from the top to block the container. I must be doing something basic wrong here.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  background: black;
  transition: max-height 2s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover .inner {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: you a setting a max-height and not the height. so the height is still 0

Comment: ah, I got stuck trying to transition the max height and forgot to give it a height too. Thanks.

Comment: The HTML you show is invalid. Fix that first.

Comment: You are right but that wasn't my issue. I was using styled components and just switched the tags to simplify the code for this example.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Temani Afif, this was nothing more than missing a height.